# Cannot summarize in R

Tags: r, summarize

I don't know why the summarize function did not work.

Here is my dataset: https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AMGFcNnnBmsa3Js&id=B09F9559F6A16B6C%2171378&cid=B09F9559F6A16B6C

Here is my code chunk:

```
orders <- read_excel("Orders.xlsx")
customers <- read_excel("Customers.xlsx")
types <- read_excel("Cookie Types.xlsx")

orders %>% mutate(cost = types$`Cost Per Cookie`*`Units Sold`, 
                   rev = types$`Revenue Per Cookie`*`Units Sold`, 
                   prof = rev - cost) %>%
group_by(Product) %>% summarize(percent = (prof / rev)*100)
```

and it resulted like this:

[image]

and I would like it to be like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Please include any example data in the question itself instead of as external links, which might not be valid links in the future. For instance, you can run `dput(head(orders))` to generate code that recreates the first few rows of that table.

Comment: `group_by` only makes the calculations to be done *for each group*. To make totals, you must also use aggregate functions. Try `summarize(percent = sum(prof) / sum(rev) * 100)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues. First, you need to join the `orders` and `types` data together.

Second, `summarize` requires a summary function, such as `sum`. Your code is dividing by group but on a per-row basis, so the summary is getting repeated.

So something like:

```
orders %>% 
  left_join(types, 
            by = c("Product" = "Cookie Type")) %>% 
  mutate(cost = `Cost Per Cookie` * `Units Sold`,
         rev = `Revenue Per Cookie` * `Units Sold`,
         prof = rev - cost) %>% 
  group_by(Product) %>% 
  summarize(percent = (sum(prof) / sum(rev)) * 100)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Product                       percent
  <chr>                           <dbl>
1 Chocolate Chip                   60  
2 Fortune Cookie                   50  
3 Oatmeal Raisin                   56  
4 Snickerdoodle                    62.5
5 Sugar                            58.3
6 White Chocolate Macadamia Nut    54.2
```

Comment: I suppose tables match already by row, because the product ```types$`Cost Per Cookie`*`Units Sold`,``` would otherwise probably fail. Of course with no data is a suspicion only.

Comment: The data is in the link ok i didnt see.

Comment: I'm so grateful for the second time you help me sir!